# how to check element id preset in dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to check element id preset in dom ?I am able to check that.But I need to use "continue"  function . If the id is already present it increase the id till get that id  which is not present in dom ?

In my Example:
"tc_1" is present Now when user press "test" but it check  "tc_2" present if not it add .same in tc_3 and tc_4 .can we do that ?
if it id is exit

http://jsfiddle.net/2dLrw/4/

```
   $(function(){
        $('#test').click(function(){                
            var id;
            if (typeof ($("#app li:last").attr('id')) == 'undefined') {
                id = "tc_1";
            } else {
                id = $("#app li:last").attr('id');
                if(!$("#" + id).length == 0) {
                       //not exist
                }
                var index = id.indexOf("_");
                var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
                count = parseInt(count);
                id = id.substring(0, index) + "_" + parseInt(count + 1);
             }                
            var html = '<li id="'+id+'">'+id+'</li>';
            $('#app').append(html);
        });            
    });
```

when user press button it add go for check that id present on dom .if it is present it increase the value of id.if increase value also present then again it increase id.it increase untill it not find new id.
It is some like recursively check if id present in dom or not

Comment: Is the pattern of Id important to you? Can it be any unique id?

Comment: pattern is anything but it start from 1 to anything ..a_1 , a_2

Comment: Okay, so can it be ui-id-1,ui-id-2,ui-id-3 etc etc?

Comment: yes it fine is fine but take that that example ui-id-1 or ui-id-4 ..tec present in dom

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha any idea of this Question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52460/discussion-between-user944513-and-kamlesh-kushwaha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your javascript

```
    $(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        var id=0;

        for(;id<10;id++){

    if(!document.getElementById("tc_"+id)){

           var html = '<li id="tc_'+id+'">'+"tc_"+id+'</li>';
           $('#app').append(html);break;
    }
}

    });

});
```

Comment: @user944513 I misunderstood something?

Comment: when user press button it add go for check that id present on dom .if it is present it increase the value of id.if increase value also present then again it increase id.it increase untill it not find new id

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted. I'm giving @nicael +1 for taking time to solve the problem.

Comment: @nicel perfect anwser

Answer (score 0):

Try this L http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/2dLrw/6/

```
$(function () {
$('#test').click(function () {
    var m = 0;
    var ul = $('#app');
    $('#app li').each(function () {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]);
        if (id > m) m = id;
    });
    m++;
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    ul.append(li);
    li.attr('id','tc_'+m).text('tc_'+m);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="app">
 <li id="tc_1">tc_1</li>
 <li id="tc_4">tc_4</li>
 <li id="tc_9">tc_9</li>
</ul>
<button id="test">test</button>
```

Note: Make sure all li have Id. Or just add a check in the JS for it.

Comment: Your html in the fiddle is wrong. Replace your html with html above

Comment: but  i said element present anywhere

Comment: If you need to check on complete HTML, then I suggest you should refer uniqueId http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/ . You need to call this function and it will automatically assign unique id in the format "ui-id-1","ui-id-2" and so on. Will it work for you?